# How to use a custom approval workflow (Copy of default)

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I need to customize the default 2010 approval workflow and I would prefer not editing the build in. I have made a copy of the workflow as described here: [How to Copy an Approval Workflow and Retain Its Custom Task Form](https://threewill.com/copy-approval-workflow-retain-custom-task-form/)

Now! How on earth do I choose to start the newly created custom approval workflow? I have published it as a new global workflow (As the changes I will be making is needed globally). I have the option to "Start Custom Task Process" from a 2010 workflow, while that does look like an approval workflow it's mostly empty and does not do even half of the build in does.

I can't seem to find anywhere I can specify to use the custom workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've searched high and low and it seems you can't start your own approval workflows from another workflow. Which in my case makes it anything but reuseable. Instead I've created a custom task action and rebuld the approval functionallity from button up.